# How Can i Upload video to Vimeo From Node js Server

Tags: node.js, rest, node-modules, vimeo, vimeo-api

This is My Code From the client Side it is working I want to do this from the server.

How can I upload a video to Vimeo?

upload is working fine from the client-side.
But I want to upload it from the Nodejs server.

// Routes

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, '')
    }
})
const ShortFilm = multer({ storage }).single('file_loc')
 Server Uploadsrouter.post('/upload-short-film',ShortFilm, UploadShortFilm.UploadShortFilm)
```

// Code

```
var filePath = req.file

let client = new Vimeo("key", "key", "key");

    var params = {
      'name': req.body.file_name,
      'description': req.body.file_desc
    }

    client.upload(filePath, params, function (uri) {
      
        // Get the metadata response from the upload and log out the Vimeo.com url
        client.request(uri + '?fields=link', function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {  
        
          if (error) {
            console.log('There was an error making the request.')
            console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
            return
          } 
          
          res.status(200).json({ "status": true, "Video-link": body.link });
          // console.log('"' + filePath + '" has been uploaded to ' + body.link)

          // Make an API call to edit the title and description of the video.
          client.request({
            method: 'PATCH',
            path: uri,
            params: {
              'name': req.body.file_name,
              'description': req.body.file_desc
            }
          },
           function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('There was an error making the request.')
              console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
              return
            }

            console.log('The title and description for ' + uri + ' has been edited.')

            // Make an API call to see if the video is finished transcoding.
            client.request( uri + '?fields=transcode.status', function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
                if (error) {
                  console.log('There was an error making the request.')
                  console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
                  return 
                }
                console.log('The transcode status for ' + uri + ' is: ' + body.transcode.status)
              }
            )
          })
        })
      },
      
      function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
        var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
        console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + '%')

      },
      function (error) {
        console.log('Failed because : ' + error)
        res.status(200).json({ "status": false, "error": error });
      }
    )
```

Vimeo says the file path should provide to upload the video. How can I provide the file path through this?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not giving it the filename. req.file is an object with alot of fields. Try passing req.file.path.

Suppose you have this definition.

```
const multerPath = '/some/psth/to/multer';

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, multerPath);
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
```

Then you can have.

```
var filePath = req.file
client.upload(`${multerPath}/${filePath.filename}`, params, function(uri) {
  ....
});
```